# Absolute positioning and z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having an issue with a couple of absolutely positioned elements and the z-index property.

If you take a look at this [reference URL](http://robotwp.com/explicite/cougar/) (Slightly NSFW) I need the purple logo in the corner to be above the woman... But I can't seem to get it to happen

Comment: -1 for the "slightly NSFW" link and for not posting the relevant code here.

Comment: See if you can provide a link to something that's slightly safer for work.

Comment: Please post your code here, or at the very least, a link to a SFW fiddle.

Comment: So, you want the purple logo to cover half the woman's face?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution.

```
<div class="woman" style="z-index:0;"></div>
```

And here's the proof that it works.

[image]